# How to set Facebook's hideFlashCallback from graphapi_web_1_8_1.swc

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, actionscript

graphapi_web_1_8_1.swc has a `Facebook.init()` function that takes pretty much the same arguments as the `FB.init()` JavaScript version. However, what I'm interested in setting is Facebook's hideFlashCallback parameter, via the `"options"` argument passed into both `Facebook.init()` and `FB.init()`. The JavaScript SDK takes a value of type `"Object"` as shown here:

> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

However, if I'm already calling graphapi_web_1_8_1.swc's `Facebook.init()` from ActionScript, how can I pass in a JavaScript function as the hideFlashCallback?

I tried using `ExternalInterface.call()` to call a `"GetHideFlashCallback()"` JS function whose return value was the callback function as an object, but it comes back as null in ActionScript, even when the ActionScript variable was typed as `"Object"` or `"*"`.

My next test is to avoid calling graphapi_web_1_8_1.swc's `Facebook.init()` and just do something like `ExternalInterface.call("FB_init_proxy(args)")` which would just use Facebook's JavaScript SDK directly.

But is there a way to pass JavaScript functions back and forth with ActionScript as Object variables? If not, why? Is it a security concern?

Comment: Did you ever get this functionality working? I am struggling with a similar scenario myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the reason of your problem here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/637/

so in the javascript init of facebook you have to add the hideFlashCallback:

```
FB.init({
    appId:appId,
    status:true,
    cookie:true,
    oauth:true,
    frictionlessRequests: true,
    hideFlashCallback : displayFlash
});
```

and in displayFlash function you can do what you want

```
function displayFlash( a )
{
    if( a.state == 'opened' )
    {
        // do what you want when a chat or notification is open
    }
    else
    {
        // do what you want when a chat or notification is closed
    }
}
```